# Windows 10 1909 running very slow in Bochs

Tags: reverse-engineering, instrumentation, bochs

When I try to boot up **Windows 10 1909** on bochs emulator, I stuck with a problem that Bochs running very very slow... there is a way to speedup bochs performance? maybe change configuration in the .bxrc file will help to slove this issue?. Because I searched all over the google/forums and didn't found noting about this topic...

***Note that I booting my Windows from CD-ROM**

Comment: Can't you copy the image to disk and use Daemon tools or something similar to mount? If it's performance is adequate afterwards, at least you know the cd-rom is to blame. If that's the case, you could try preloading the entire cd in memory or create an in-memory drive. On an unrelated note: you are not this [stök](https://hackerone.com/stok) by any chance?

Comment: Thank's for the answer and no I'm not this stok :))... so what you trying to say is that i should mount the .ISO in Daemon tools?

Comment: Yes. Copy it to a harddrive and mount. I would try that as to eliminate possible cd performance issues This is just a first step into determining what the issue is mind you. I have zero experience with Bochs.

Comment: Ok, thank's I'll try that!